# ListView adapter data change without ListView being notified

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter, notify

I've written a ListActivity that has a custom list adapter.  The list is being updated from a ContentProvider when onCreate is run.  I also have a service that gets started when I run the app and it first updates the ContentProvider, then sends a Broadcast that the content has been updated.
  My ListActivity receives the broadcast and tries to update my ListView.  My problem is, I'm getting intermittent errors about the ListView adapter data changing without the ListView being notified.  I call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on my list adapter right after I update it.  What it seems like is happening is the list is still in the process of being updated after first call in onCreate when it receives the broadcast from the service to update, so it tries to update my ListView before it's finished updating from it's first run.  Does this make sense?  Here is some of my code.

NOTE: The service is working properly, it gets new data and updates my ContentProvider, and I do get the broadcast in my activity when it is updated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    getPrefs();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Setup preference listener
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);


    // Setup report list adapter
    ListView nzbLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.report_list);
    nzbla = new NZBReportListAdaptor(ctx);
    getReports();
    nzbla.setListItems(report_list);            
    nzbLv.setAdapter(nzbla);        
    // Broadcast receiver to get notification from NZBService to update ReportList
    registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter(NZBService.BROADCAST_ACTION));

    startService(new Intent(ctx, NZBService.class));
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    timerHandler.resume();      
new updateSabQueue().execute();
    //updateList();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    timerHandler.pause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}


private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "NZBService broadcast recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateReportList();
    }
};


private void updateReportList() {
    new updateReportList().execute();
}



private class updateReportList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     * Show progress dialog
     */
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     * Get new articles from the internet
     */
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...unused) {
        getReports();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * On post execute.
     * Close the progress dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean updated) {
        if (updated) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NZB report list adapter updated");
            synchronized(this) {
                nzbla.setListItems(report_list);            
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "NZB report list notified of change");
            nzbla.notifyDataSetChanged();                           
        }
    }
}
```

Now that this question is answered, I will post my updated code in an effort to help others who might come across it.

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ctx = this;
    getPrefs();
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Setup preference listener
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

    // Setup report list adapter
    ListView nzbLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.report_list);
    nzbla = new NZBReportListAdaptor(ctx);
    report_list.addAll(getReports());
    nzbla.setListItems(report_list);            
    nzbLv.setAdapter(nzbla);        
    // Broadcast receiver to get notification from NZBService to update ReportList
    registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter(NZBService.BROADCAST_ACTION));

    startService(new Intent(ctx, NZBService.class));
}


private class updateReportList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Report>> {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
     * Show progress dialog
     */
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     * Get new articles from the internet
     */
    protected ArrayList<Report> doInBackground(Void...unused) {
        return getReports();
    }

    /**
     * On post execute.
     * Close the progress dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Report> updated) {
        nzbla.setListItems(updated);            
        nzbla.notifyDataSetChanged();                           
    }
}


private ArrayList<Report> getReports() {
    ArrayList<Report> reports = new ArrayList<Report>();
    ContentResolver r = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = r.query(NZBReportProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_ROWID + " DESC");
    startManagingCursor(c);
    Log.d(TAG, "NZBReport cursor.getCount=" + c.getCount());
    int title = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_TITLE);
    int desc = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_DESCRIPTION);
    int cat = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_CAT);
    int size = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_SIZE);
    int link = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_LINK);
    int catid = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_CATID);
    int date = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_DATE_ADDED);
    int group = c.getColumnIndex(NZBReportProvider.ARTICLE_KEY_GROUP);

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(c.getString(link));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            reports.add(new Report(c.getString(title), url, c.getString(desc), c.getString(cat), c.getString(date), c.getString(size), c.getInt(catid), c.getString(group)));               
        } while (c.moveToNext());                   
    }
    return reports;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to do all your updating of Adapter data on the UI thread so the synchronized block isn't necessary. It's also useless since your synchronizing on the `AsyncTask` which is created new each time it's executed.

Another problem is that you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` external to the `Adapter`. You should call it at the end of your `setListItems` method. That shouldn't be causing errors though since it's being executed on the UI thread but it should not be called in that way.

You should make sure that your `getReports` method is not modifying the backing store of the `Adapter` in any way. Since it is running on a separate thread it cannot modify anything the `Adapter` has access too. Even if it's protected by locks. What you need to do is in your `doInBackground` method is generate the list of updates or a new list, etc., and pass that into `onPostExecute` which then commits the new data to the `Adapter` on the UI thread. So, if your `getReports` function is changing `report_list` and your `Adapter` has a reference to `report_list` you are doing it wrong. `getReports` must create a new `report_list` and then pass that back to your `Adapter` when it's finished creating it on the UI thread.

To reiterate, you can only modify data the `Adapter` and subsequently the `ListView` has access too on the UI thread. Using synchronization/locks does not change this requirement.

Comment: This is exactly the problem.  My list adapter is backed by an ArrayList of objects "report_list" and I'm modifying it directly in my getReports method that is executing on a separate thread.  I modified my getReports method to operate on a local ArrayList and return it (and pass it on to my onPostExecute method).  While I was aware of the fact that I can't operate on my list adapter data outside of the UI thread, I just wasn't grasping it 100% until it failed me and forced me to figure it out properly (or more accurately ask for help here!)  Thank you Qberticus!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to update the UI listview from a service then you should call notifyDataSetChanged() on  onDestroy of the service

make the adapter static from your main activity and call that adaptername.notifyDataSetChanged()

like this

```
@Override
       public void onDestroy() {

               if (MainActivity.isInFront == true) {
                       if (MainActivity.adapter != null)
                               MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       MainActivity.listView.setAdapter(MainActivity.adapter);
               }
}
```

Comment: Huh? You can't make the adapter static and call non static methods like notifyDataSetChanged from it. Heck, there isn't even a method called isInFront, even if there was, you can't just call is on the class since it wouldn't be static.

Comment: is in  front is a method which you have to make.. there's no spoon feeding going on here..understand the code first then downvote...

Comment: You can't define a static method that checks for the state of an instance. Also you can't access the instance of any activity without at least a reference to it, or setting a listener interface to update the activity through that. Another reason why I downvoted is because you have to get all running tasks to know which activity is in the front, let alone fetch an instance of that Activity, which is completely unnecessary. Even if you manually maintain an isInFront boolean, you won't be able to fetch the instance so easily.

Comment: Better yet, set a listener in the adapter and update the adapter class when the backend data set changes. That way, you only need to update the data set in the service to update the adapter state.