# How to use both BroadcastReceiver & ListActivity in same code

Tags: android, android-listview, broadcastreceiver

Two classes are required for this project.

- `BroadcastReceiver` (class) — to receive SMS;
- `ListActivity` (class) — to display SMS;

Because `setListAdapter()` method requires defined `ListActivity` (class), my question is how should I define both classes in the following codes?

```
import ....
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";     
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                      
        }

        //----REQUIRE ListActivity(class) to define----//
        // how should i define the class here???

        //---display in list---
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,str));
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        //---method is call when listitem is clicked---
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            //described method
        });
    }                         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest Solution according to me is:

- 1 Store all the items in a list in class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`
- 2 Pass the list with `Intent` to class that extends `ListActivity`

Comment: @kin-You should always accept a correct answer as it could help others who has a similar problem and check this question !!!

Answer (score 1):

Kin, You can also set listview in the Activity without Extending Listview. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636679/listview-adapter-data-change-without-listview-being-notified).