# How to delete item from expandable drag and drop list view in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, expandablelistview

I have used expandable drag and drop list view in my android app.I want to that when  drag particular item from list and drop item on delete box(means delete that item from exapdable listview).I have searched many link but I have not got any useful link.Please suggested me link and source code.

Thanks

Comment: I am developing an app that requires drag and drop expandable listview. I badly need a code that will help me. Can you please post your code or any link containing some easy example. Thankyou in advance

Comment: @SyamantakBasu https://github.com/XxGoliathusxX/LightWeightExpandableDragAndSwipeRecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to change the elements you are populating your list with (to remove the item you want removed), then call the notifyDataSetChanged() method on your adapter.

This is one good SO question I saw regarding this: [ListView adapter data change without ListView being notified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636679/listview-adapter-data-change-without-listview-being-notified)

Comment: @Deepak I am in search of a good example of Drag and Drop Expandable listview. Can please post your code or any good example. Thanks in advance.